# Making sense of the allele frequency weighted genetic distance

Tags: distance-functions, genetics

I found one formula to calculate the pairwise distance between samples according to their SNPs in the following paper: Siu, Jin and Xiong, [Manifold Learning for Human Population Structure
Studies](http://www.plosone.org/article/fetchObject.action?uri=info%3adoi/10.1371/journal.pone.0029901&representation=PDF), PLoS One (2012) 7(1), p. 13. The formula is

$d = 1-\frac{1}{2k}\sum_{j=1}^k (\frac{1}{P_{A_j}}IBS_{A_j}+\frac{1}{P_{a_j}}IBS_{a_j}+\frac{1}{P_{N_j}}IBS_{N_j})$

where $IBS_{A_j},IBS_{a_j},IBS_{N_j}$ be the number of copies of alleles $A_j,a_j$ and missing allele $N_j$ at the $j$-th SNP shared by the pair of individuals, respectively, and $P_{A_j},P_{a_j},P_{N_j}$ are the frequencies of the alleles $A_j,a_j,$ and $N_j$, respectively, and $k$ is the number of SNPs.

For simplicity, let's assume that there is no missing values and $k=1$. We would have cases like AA-AA, Aa-Aa, aa-aa, AA-Aa, Aa-aa, AA-aa.

The distance for the first three case should be $0$. Let's use the formula to calculate the case for Aa-Aa: we should have $IBS_A=1,IBS_a=1,P_A=\frac{1}{2},P_a=\frac{1}{2}$, then the formula gives me a negative distance. How could that be possible?

To my understanding, $d$ can equal to $0,\frac{2}{3},1$. We have $\frac{2}{3}$ because 'weighted'? Is there any other formula to calculate the pairwise distance according to sample's SNPs?